# Sri Hayavadana Kavacham (alternately, Sri Hayagreeva Kavacham)

Tags: vishnu, vishishtadvaita, atharva-veda

Sri Hayavadana Perumaal is the Horse headed Avatara of Sriman Narayana. Kavacha Stotram or Kavacham are hymns of Exhortation and/or Reassurance with an usual intended effect of bestowing protection to the reciter/listener. Literally, Kavacham means Divine Armour.

Sri Hayavadana Kavacham or Sri Hayagreeva Kavacham, as can be listened to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTsaI7WnkOw&t=2787s) and read about [here](http://stotrarathna.blogspot.in/2014/02/hayagreeva-kavacham.html), is a Kavacha Stotram said to belong to the Poorva samhitha of Atharva Vedam (said to be seen or received as revelation by Sage Hayagreeva). This Kavacham focuses on protection of various aspects of the body by exhortation to various divine aspects of the Cosmos with an overarching relational reference to Sri Hayavadana Perumaal, moves next to the guarding of the ten directions by various divine aspects, states that "giving up the body will result in becoming as god of speech" (***Yevam nyastha sareero  asou sakshad  Vageeswara bhaved***) and as final exhortation seeks Lord Hayagreeva's grace and bestowal of knowledge & wisdom of Shaastras.

I'm interested in the following:

1. Is the Atharva Veda Shakha(recension) where this Kavacham is from intact even today? Please provide reference to the same.
2. Who is Sage Hayagreeva?
3. How should ***Yevam nyastha sareero  asou sakshad  Vageeswara bhaved*** be interpreted in the context of the Kavacham in so far as it is related to *Viśiṣṭādvaita*?

Comment: idk about kavacham since it has beeja mantras  which only dvijas can learn and that too from qualified acharya.. while swami desikan's hayagreeva stotram same results and can be easily learned